# Returning an int array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, integer

So I need a script that returns an array of a text document. The document is all numbers. Everytime I try to run it I get this message "This method must return a result of type int[]" this is under the checker part. I am trying to return it to another class so that I can use the array for if statements. Could anyone help me out with this?

```
import java.io.File; // Import the File class
import java.io.FileNotFoundException; // Import this class to handle errors
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner; // Import the Scanner class to read text files

public class ReadFile {
public static int[] checker(){
    try {
        File myObj = new File("Tracker.txt");
        Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
        while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
            String data = myReader.nextLine();
            String[] moreData = data.split("\n");
            int day = Integer.parseInt(moreData[0]);
            int Posts = Integer.parseInt(moreData[1]);
            return new int[] {day, Posts};
        }
        
        myReader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        return new int[] {0, 0};
    }
    }

}
```

Expected outcome is: {0, 40}

Comment: Please show us what the expected output from your method is supposed to be.  It is not clear from your code, which is rife with problems.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to java and still trying to figure it out.

Comment: I added the expected outcome

Comment: All possible return paths must return an `int[]`. In your code it's possible that `myReader.hasNextLine()` could return `false`. In that case, no `return` statement can be reached because neither the `while` loop nor the `catch` block are entered.

Comment: *"The document is all numbers"* - in what ways?  Are they on separate lines?  Separated by spaces? It's kind of difficult to suggest an accurate solution to the problem, beyond fix the obvious compiler error

Comment: @MadProgrammer They numbers seperated by line breaks like so :
0
40
30

Comment: well it wont let me but \n breaks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is complaining because it thinks there is a possible exit path which skips all the other `return` statements.  What happens if `hasNextLine` returns `false` on the first interaction?

In this case, you should move the `return` in the `catch` clause to the end of the method

```
import java.io.File; // Import the File class
import java.io.FileNotFoundException; // Import this class to handle errors
import java.util.Scanner; // Import the Scanner class to read text files

public class ReadFile {

    public static int[] checker() {
        File myObj = new File("Tracker.txt");
        // This will ensure that the Scanner is closed when
        // you exit from the loop early
        try (Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj)) {
            while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
                String data = myReader.nextLine();
                // Why?  You just read the line, there
                // are no more lines in this text?!
                String[] moreData = data.split("\n");
                int day = Integer.parseInt(moreData[0]);
                int Posts = Integer.parseInt(moreData[1]);
                // Why?? Are there only two values in the
                // whole file?!  Then you should use if (...) instead of while (...)
                return new int[]{day, Posts};
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // You should at least print an error   
        }
        return new int[]{0, 0};
    }

}
```

Have a look at [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for more information on what `try (Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj)) {` is doing

> They numbers seperated by line breaks like so : 0 40 30

So, a better solution might look something like...

```
public static int[] checker() {
    File myObj = new File("Tracker.txt");
    List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>(128);
    try (Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj)) {
        while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
            String data = myReader.nextLine();
            int value = Integer.parseInt(data);
            values.add(value);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong");
    }
    return values.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
}
```

The problem with using an array of this, is the fact that you don't know how many lines (or elements) there are, so, you need something more dynamic, like a `List`, which you can continuously add new elements to, without needing to know how many you need to store up front.

This is a little more "advanced", but generally, I would consider using `List` over arrays in most cases, but that's me and I'm lazy.

> Expected outcome is: {0, 40}

If you only want a fixed number of elements, then count the number of lines you've read and exit early when you've reached it

```
public static int[] checker() {
    File myObj = new File("Tracker.txt");
    try (Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj)) {
        int line = 0;
        int[] values = new int[2];
        while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
            String data = myReader.nextLine();
            int value = Integer.parseInt(data);
            values[line] = value;
            line += 1;
            if (line > 1) {
                // Early exit
                break;
            }
        }
        return values;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong");
    }
    return new int[] { 0, 0 };
}
```

Comment: ...but this method makes no sense, because the `while` loop will return after the first iteration, which almost certainly is not the logic the OP wants.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Since I was only asked to fix the compiler error - this is what I did.  I didn't try to reason about "what" the OP was actually trying to do.  If the file only contains a single line of text then `if(myReader.hasNextLine())` would be more appropriate - but why are they trying to split the line they just read with a new line character?!  It'd be nice to see the expected data structure of the file :P

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I appreciate it. Like I said I'm new to Java, So I'm just feeling my way around. But I would love feed back if you have any??

Comment: @AaronCloud Well, apart from fixing your compiler error, we really can't fix the logic, because we don't have enough context.  For example, you read a line of text from the file, but then try splitting the text on a new line marker ... but that won't work, because you just read the line of text, there won't be any other lines in it.  Does the file contain a single line?  Does it contain multiple lines?  Does each line consist of just one number of a number of numbers?  If so, how are the delimitated?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Your answer does fix the exact problem asked +1.  Just commenting that the _best_ answer would be to give a completely working method.